# Ошибки при импорте csv в mySQL.

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

После импорта csv в mySQL при попытке удалить строку phpmyadmin выдает вот такую ошибку:

Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

и:

phpMyAdmin - Error
Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent
session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.

Дело в том, что если я импортировал 20 строк в таблицу, то при попытке удаления строки эти ошибки есть. А если 5 строк - то все нормально, удаляю строку, и все проходит без ошибок.

Как это исправить, подскажите пожалуйста. 
Благодарю заранее!

Comment: Ну пишут же: *To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini*.

Comment: Я изменил этот параметр, это не помогло.

Comment: На какое значение? если 1000 хватает для 5 записей и нехватает для 6, то для 20 записей потребуется 4000. Ну так, чисто арифметика...

Comment: Изменил на 5000.

Comment: А если записей 2 900 000? Собственно цель такая.

Comment: Ну ещё подкорректируйте php_value max_input_vars в .htaccess.

Comment: *Собственно цель такая.* Уходите от визуальной корректировки к запросам. Вот и всё...

Comment: ... Уходите от визуальной корректировки к запросам. Вот и всё. Благодарю вас!